# Azure DevOps pipeline task `task: gitversion/execute@0` fails with unexpected error "##[error]SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input"

Tags: azure-devops, pipeline, gitversion, azure-yaml-pipelines

I was running the pipeline with a simple task to install the git and check the version by the following `tasks`.

Everything was running well till the time I created another temporary pipeline with the same yaml file for some additional tests and development.

I did not change anything from the yaml file which is running green still, with the same tasks.

But the execute task in the new pipeline fails with an 'unexpected' error

```
  steps:
    - task: gitversion/setup@0
      displayName: Install GitVersion
      inputs:
        versionSpec: "5.10.x"
    
    - task: gitversion/execute@0
      displayName: Determine Version
      inputs:
        useConfigFile: true
        configFilePath: ./gitversion.yml
```

The output looks like this:

```
Command: dotnet-gitversion /agent/_work/26/s /output json /output buildserver /config /agent/_work/26/s/gitversion.yml
/opt/hostedtoolcache/GitVersion.Tool/5.10.3/x64/dotnet-gitversion /agent/_work/26/s /output json /output buildserver /config /agent/_work/26/s/gitversion.yml
  ERROR [09/20/22 12:54:22:24] An unexpected error occurred:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Handles.ObjectHandle.op_Implicit(ObjectHandle handle) in /_/LibGit2Sharp/Core/Handles/Objects.cs:line 509
   at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Proxy.git_commit_author(ObjectHandle obj) in /_/LibGit2Sharp/Core/Proxy.cs:line 289
   at LibGit2Sharp.Core.LazyGroup`1.Dependent`2.LibGit2Sharp.Core.LazyGroup<T>.IEvaluator<TInput>.Evaluate(TInput input) in /_/LibGit2Sharp/Core/LazyGroup.cs:line 88
   at LibGit2Sharp.Core.LazyGroup`1.<Evaluate>b__6_0(T input) in /_/LibGit2Sharp/Core/LazyGroup.cs:line 36
   at LibGit2Sharp.Core.GitObjectLazyGroup.EvaluateInternal(Action`1 evaluator) in /_/LibGit2Sharp/Core/GitObjectLazyGroup.cs:line 20
   at LibGit2Sharp.Core.LazyGroup`1.Evaluate() in /_/LibGit2Sharp/Core/LazyGroup.cs:line 34
   at LibGit2Sharp.Core.LazyGroup`1.Dependent`2.Evaluate() in /_/LibGit2Sharp/Core/LazyGroup.cs:line 80
   at LibGit2Sharp.Core.LazyGroup`1.Dependent`2.get_Value() in /_/LibGit2Sharp/Core/LazyGroup.cs:line 73
   at LibGit2Sharp.Commit.get_Committer() in /_/LibGit2Sharp/Commit.cs:line 87
   at GitVersion.Commit..ctor(Commit innerCommit) in D:\a\GitVersion\GitVersion\src\GitVersion.LibGit2Sharp\Git\Commit.cs:line 17
   at GitVersion.Commit.<>c.<.ctor>b__3_0(Commit parent) in D:\a\GitVersion\GitVersion\src\GitVersion.LibGit2Sharp\Git\Commit.cs:line 16
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Count[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at GitVersion.Configuration.BranchConfigurationCalculator.InheritBranchConfiguration(Int32 recursions, IBranch targetBranch, BranchConfig branchConfiguration, ICommit currentCommit, Config configuration, IList`1 excludedInheritBranches) in D:\a\GitVersion\GitVersion\src\GitVersion.Core\Configuration\BranchConfigurationCalculator.cs:line 77
   at GitVersion.Configuration.BranchConfigurationCalculator.GetBranchConfigurationInternal(Int32 recursions, IBranch targetBranch, ICommit currentCommit, Config configuration, IList`1 excludedInheritBranches) in D:\a\GitVersion\GitVersion\src\GitVersion.Core\Configuration\BranchConfigurationCalculator.cs:line 54


....
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at GitVersion.GitVersionCalculateTool.CalculateVersionVariables() in D:\a\GitVersion\GitVersion\src\GitVersion.Core\Core\GitVersionCalculateTool.cs:line 52
   at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Handles.ObjectHandle.op_Implicit(ObjectHandle handle) in /_/LibGit2Sharp/Core/Handles/Objects.cs:line 509
   at GitVersion.GitVersionExecutor.RunGitVersionTool(GitVersionOptions gitVersionOptions) in D:\a\GitVersion\GitVersion\src\GitVersion.App\GitVersionExecutor.cs:line 66
   at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Proxy.git_commit_author(ObjectHandle obj) in /_/LibGit2Sharp/Core/Proxy.cs:line 289
   at LibGit2Sharp.Core.LazyGroup`1.Dependent`2.LibGit2Sharp.Core.LazyGroup<T>.IEvaluator<TInput>.Evaluate(TInput input) in /_/LibGit2Sharp/Core/LazyGroup.cs:line 88
   at LibGit2Sharp.Core.LazyGroup`1.<Evaluate>b__6_0(T input) in /_/LibGit2Sharp/Core/LazyGroup.cs:line 36
   at LibGit2Sharp.Core.GitObjectLazyGroup.EvaluateInternal(Action`1 evaluator) in /_/LibGit2Sharp/Core/GitObjectLazyGroup.cs:line 20
   at LibGit2Sharp.Core.LazyGroup`1.Evaluate() in /_/LibGit2Sharp/Core/LazyGroup.cs:line 34

.....
   at GitVersion.VersionCalculation.NextVersionCalculator.get_context() in D:\a\GitVersion\GitVersion\src\GitVersion.Core\VersionCalculation\NextVersionCalculator.cs:line 15
   at GitVersion.VersionCalculation.NextVersionCalculator.FindVersion() in D:\a\GitVersion\GitVersion\src\GitVersion.Core\VersionCalculation\NextVersionCalculator.cs:line 30
   at GitVersion.GitVersionCalculateTool.CalculateVersionVariables() in D:\a\GitVersion\GitVersion\src\GitVersion.Core\Core\GitVersionCalculateTool.cs:line 52
   at GitVersion.GitVersionExecutor.RunGitVersionTool(GitVersionOptions gitVersionOptions) in D:\a\GitVersion\GitVersion\src\GitVersion.App\GitVersionExecutor.cs:line 66
  INFO [09/20/22 9:44:27:78] Attempting to show the current git graph (please include in issue): 
  INFO [09/20/22 9:44:27:78] Showing max of 100 commits
  INFO [09/20/22 9:44:27:80] * 03932e8 2 hours ago  (grafted, HEAD -> feature/legok8sdeploy, origin/03932e8129e442c335e9ffd69a88b0ce4df3a3f0, 03932e8129e442c335e9ffd69a88b0ce4df3a3f0)

  INFO [09/20/22 9:44:27:82] Done writing 
##[error]SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
```

The error doesn't seem to be very intuitive.

I could find a GitHub issue opened here:

https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion/issues/3081

But this doesn't give any solution to resolve and make the task green again.

> Note: I'm running it from my branch and not main.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The cause of the issue could be related to the fetch depth of the Pipeline repo.

By default, the Shallow fetch of the pipeline repo is  1 by default.

You can try to set the **fetchDepth** to **0** in YAML Pipeline.

For example:

```
steps:
    - checkout: self
      fetchDepth: 0
    - task: gitversion/setup@0
      displayName: Install GitVersion
      inputs:
        versionSpec: "5.10.x"
    
    - task: gitversion/execute@0
      displayName: Determine Version
      inputs:
        useConfigFile: true
        configFilePath: ./gitversion.yml
```

Or you can navigate to **YAML Pipeline -> ... -> Triggers -> YAML -> Get sources -> Shallow fetch**.  You can unselect the option.

[image]

[image]

Comment: where can i find the documentation of arguments etc for gitversion/execute@0